# GWT History support for host-page hash-href's in Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, browser-history

Is my understanding correct, that I cannot use something like `<a href="#Contact">Contact</a>` in the host-page for my GWT app and have it work correctly with the GWT History management in IE 6 through 8? I read somewhere that I have to have my GWT app go through the entire loader html page and replace all hrefs with GWT links?

What I'm seeing in IE7 is that either the browser refreshes the whole page when I click one of the #-links or the GWT History ValueChangeHandler doesn't get called, but the url gets updated silently.

I do have the iframe in the hostpage and everything works beautifully in all other browsers I tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It unfortunately is.

Have a look at: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2152

Comment: That's where I saw it... There were actually several issues in the tracker regarding this topic in one way or another. Most of them said something about having to get to your page via a 302 redirect to trigger this error, though, and I couldn't find anywhere whether it was a generally problem also. That's why I posted it here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS Polyfill to support the History Management:

Modernizer uses Histroy.js:
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Thers a Modernizer for GWT:
https://github.com/jDramaix/gwtmodernizr

I don't know if there History API works with gwtmodernizer. You should try it.